# Prove that the limit of $X_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity is $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-explanation

$|X_{n+1}| \leq K|X_n \; | \; n=1,2,...$

K is a constant $0<K<1$.

Prove that the limit of $X_n$ as $n$ approaches infinity is $0$.

Not sure how to find a limit of something that is just defined as $X_n$.

Also,
Provide examples for the following statement.

• $\{X_n\}$ is an unbounded sequence but its limit is not $∞$.
• $\{X_n\}$ is a bounded sequence but it does not have any finite limit.
• $\{X_n\}$ does not have finite limit but it has several convergent   subsequence.

I have an example for the first one,
$$Xn= \{1 \; \text{when n is odd}, n \; \text{when n is even}\}$$

Not sure about the other two though.

Comment: (1) {-1,1,-2,2,-3,3,...} (2) {0,1,0,1..}, (3) X_n = 1 for all n except every n that is a fibonacci number X_n = 2^n

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant $X_{n+1}$ instead of $X_n +1$. Then, just expand it:
$$
\lvert X_n\rvert \leq K\lvert X_{n-1}\rvert \leq K^2\lvert X_{n-2}\rvert 
\leq \dots \leq K^n\lvert X_{0}\rvert. 
$$
Then use the squeeze theorem: $$ 0 \leq \lvert X_n\rvert \leq K^n\lvert X_{0}\rvert\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\ ?$$

For the other questions: consider the sequences: $a_n = (-1)^n n$, and $b_n = (-1)^n$. Between the two of them, they cover all three cases you asked examples for.

Comment: Thank you! Is the example I had for the first on of the 3 statements okay though?

Comment: Yes, it is: it does not converge to $\infty$ (as it takes value $1$ infinitely often) but is unbounded.

Answer (score 0):

To show in an
elementary way
that
$k^n \to 0$
if $0 < k < 1$:

Since
$0 < k < 1$,
$k = \frac1{1+b}$
where
$b = \frac1{k}-1$.

Then,
by Bernoulli's inequality,
$(1+b)^n
\ge 1+bn
> bn$,
so
$k^n
= \frac1{(1+b)^n}
< \frac1{bn}
$.
To make $k^n \lt \epsilon$,
it is enough if
$\frac1{bn} \lt \epsilon$
or
$n > \frac1{bn}
= \frac1{n(\frac1{k}-1)}
$.

This is, of course,
not as accurate
as using logs,
but it is more elementary
since logs are not used.